# Disable/Enable NETWORK_PROVIDER on Android?

Tags: android, networking, provider

How can I enable/disable NETWORK_PROVIDER on my AVD?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
   @Override
   protected void onResume(){
      super.onResume();

      LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_PROVIDER);
      if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) Log.e("D", "ONLINE !");
      else Log.e("D", "OFFLINE !");
   }
}
```

Each time when Activity is created I am getting via Logcat: OFFLINE !
How to turn on NETWORK_PROVIDER on AVD? As you can see, "Google's location service" is active.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424564/activating-network-location-provider-in-the-android-emulator